# Building Class Library every time running Console Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I've got a Class Library Project and its content is depending on a file which is created by a console application. How do I achieve that my Class Library Project is rebuild while my Console Application is running?

I added the Class Library PRoject to my Console Application Project and added the reference of the Class Library Project. So far so good. But how to call a Rebuild of the .dll itself?

My goal is that I create NUnit TestCases within my Console Application. My Class Library reads a file with the created TestCases and builds the .dll afterwards. How can i automate that process?

Comment: You will need the build the original source to rebuild the dll. You could probably do some changes to your build settings to also build that project as well. If your data is going to constantly be changing on build, then it would probably be a better idea to have the library load in the file rather than embed the data. That way data can be different on every build and not cause re-builds on your library.

Comment: There is just one change, every time. After running console application, the class library has to be re-build.